# Is it possible to change the color of a border every 75px?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to put a border with 3 alternating colors with a height of 75px on both the left side and right side of my website. The left side was easy - there were many divs each with a height of 75px. I simply used the CSS nth-of-type selector to alternate the border colors. The right side of my website, however, is a div of unknown width and height that contains the content of my website. How can I achieve the same effect if I'm unable to use the nth-of-type selector?

Here's a section of the border of my left hand page:

[image: Example colored stripe]

I'd prefer not to use images. CSS3 is fine as long as it gracefully degrades if the user's browser isn't up to spec.

Comment: I'd think you could probably achieve this with repeating css gradients. Not well versed enough to tell you how, but read here maybe for a jump-start http://demo.hongkiat.com/css3-repeating-gradients/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: How many colors are there going to be in the border? 3?

Comment: Yup, just 3 colors, but it would be nice to have the option to change that in the future.

Answer (score 3):

you may use a `repeating-linear-gradient` with `background-size` or an image to fake that border.

```
 div {
   height:300px;
   background:repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#0194BE 0, #0194BE 75px, orange 75px, orange 150px, #E2D397 150px, #E2D397 225px) repeat-y;
   background-size:2px 225px;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yDqrb

Else look for the use of `border-image` http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images.

if you use multiple background, you can draw all borders and even do the fake columns

Comment: updated, this was to show you the method, do you need a third one right in middle ?