# CSS, border-top with 3 colors, is possible?

Tags: html, css

It is possible with css have a border-top in the same line with three colors? I already did it with images, but I was trying to learn how to do the same effect with only css but I´m not having sucess.

My border html:

```
<div class="border">
</div>
```

What I´m trying in css without sucess:

```
.border {
            border-top: 3px solid red;
            position: relative; }    

.border:after {
        position: absolute;
        left: 25%;
        border-top: 3px solid blue;}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use background-gradient too wich is alike image : (maybe a duplicate see
[Is it possible to change the color of a border every 75px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538579/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-border-every-75px/21538708#21538708) )

Here it could be :

```
element {
   background:
     linear-gradient(
       to left,
       red 0, 
       red 33.3%,
       orange 33.3%, 
       orange 66.6%, 
       blue 66.6%, 
       blue )no-repeat;
   background-size:100% 3px ;
   padding-top:3px;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lAsvw

Comment: Thank you, what a good solution! I didn´t remeber about the gradients! Really good!

Comment: you are welcome, you can even play with it : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jdwgG , have fun :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use box-shadow to achieve this effect with pure css as @Adrift mentioned above. you can only use the border type of solid. Be sure to check if the browser supports box-shadow. Note how the comma is used.

```
.border {
    box-shadow : 0 -5px 0 red,
                 0 -10px 0 blue,
                 0 -15px 0 yellow;
}
```

Another option is to use a border image.

Comment: Thank you! I already use the border image and it works but I´m trying to learn how to do with css. But I Want a line with tree colors but in the same line!

Comment: In that case just remove the line returns in the above, I added them so the code would be easily readable and understandable.

.border {box-shadow : 0 -5px 0 red,0 -10px 0 blue,0 -15px 0 yellow;}

tada ;-) glad I could help.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking for is the `border-top` **only** to have three colors **horizontally**. That's a **lot** harder.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few more tweaks to the same idea and it work fine. 
Below in line:
http://jsfiddle.net/5bVc5/3/

```
.border {
    border-top: 3px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
.border:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid blue;
    content:'';
    z-index: -1;
}
.border:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right: 0;

    left: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid green;
    content:'';
    z-index: -1;
}

<div class="border">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea.

```
.border {
    border-top: 3px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
.border:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid blue;
    content:'';
    z-index: -1;
}
.border:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid yellow;
    content:'';
    z-index: -1;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bVc5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do somthing like this :

```
.border {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

.border:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 0px;
    border-top: 5px solid yellow;
    content:'';
    z-index: -1;
}
.border:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    content:'';
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and notice that the `.border:before` border-width must be Multiplied by three of the `.border:after` border-width

**[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoudSarhan/zJ8A4/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I create a new version to border-top, border-bottom and border right or left...

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <div class="border top"><span>hello</span></div>
  <br>
  <div class="border side"><span>hello</span></div>
  <br>
  <div class="border bottom"><span>hello</span></div>
  <br>
  <div class="border bottom side top"><span>hello</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.border {
    position: relative;
    padding: 9px;
    border: 0 solid green;
}
.border:after, 
.border:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content:'';
}
.border:after {
  border: 0 solid red;
}
.border:before {
  border: 0 solid blue;
}

.border.top, 
.border.top:after,
.border.top:before {
  border-top-width: 3px;
}
.border.bottom, 
.border.bottom:after,
.border.bottom:before {
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
}
.border.side, 
.border.side:after,
.border.side:before {
  border-right-width: 3px;
  border-left-width: 3px;
}

.border.top:before {
  top: 3px;
}
.border.bottom:before {
  bottom: 3px;
}
.border.side:before {
  left: 3px;
  right: 3px;
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bxo6ktf/